# java skew heap merging

Tags: java, algorithm, merge, heap

Doesnt' have to be java, but I'm trying to understand the merging process for a skew heap. I don't get why the part in bold below in the steps is the way it is.

- Compare roots of two heaps; let p be
  the heap with the smaller root, and q
  be the other heap.
- Let r be the name of the resulting
  new heap.
- Let the root of r be the root of p
  (the smaller root), and **let r's right
  subtree be p's left subtree.**
- **Now, compute r's left subtree by
  recursively merging p's right subtree
  with q.**

Can the algorithm be modified along an axis of symmetry (e.g I do the mirror reflection of the tree) and let r's left subtree be p's right subtree and recursively merge down the right side of r? Is it just a convention or is it more efficient to do it the way listed above?

Comment: Why do you think reflection has anything to do with the skew heap?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, but i didn't mean reflection to be any type of programming term. I just meant that in the bold text anytime u see the word "left" replace it with "right" and vice versa. Basically, if you merge two full heaps of the same size does the left subtree have to end up being the much deeper one or can it be a "reflection" in that the right subtree ends up being the deeper one.

Comment: @jhul87: Thanks! Now I understand better. Term "reflection" has a very specific meaning in the Java world, which is quite different from what you describe.

Comment: It would seem it has to do with the comparative order which is the basis of the algorithm's every step.  You are repeatedly taking a right sub-tree (where higher values are) of the smaller tree and adjusting the larger tree's left sub-tree (where lower values are).  So flipping it would need to merge *more nodes* since you are trying to fit the larger tree p's nodes into smaller r.

Comment: @Olaf, my bad, I'm still pretty new with Java so I didn't realize that would be confusing.

Comment: @alphazero, I don't think there's an ordering of siblings in heaps is there? Shouldn't it be just as likely for larger values to be in the left or right subtree of any of the original heaps to be merged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of left/right is completely arbitrary, but once you make it you have to stick with it.  After all, you could just take your heap, draw a picture of it, then mirror it and it would still be a valid heap.  The underlying reason for this is that you can take any program, and swap all occurrences of the variables left and right, and the resulting program will still be valid, and moreover do exactly the same thing.